# Multi-website, Multi-user web server with webmin

Tags: apache, permissions, vps, webmin

Lets say I have 3 domains "example.com", "example.net", and "example.org".

I also have a VPS running Ubuntu 11.04 32bit with Apache, MySQL, PHP5, ProFTPd and Webmin.

Sally owns example.com and has her home at:

> /home/sally

Joe owns example.net and has his home at:

> /home/joe

Dave owns example.org and has his home at:

> /home/dave

My Questions are:
1. How can I get them from not accessing each others directories, more specifically others websites files.
2. How can I let Apache read from the directories if each of their websites are at

> ~/htdocs/example.***/

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create some virtual host config files for Apache. Check out [How To Setup Apache Virtual Host Configuration (With Examples)](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/apache-virtual-host/), & direct fr httpd.apache.org @ [VirtualHost Examples](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html)

Don't forget to restart the Apache server (via */etc/init.d/apache2 restart* (??))

Full disclosure: I work w/ CentOS but IIRC Ubuntu's Apache directories should be the same as Debians. Be aware you may have to adjust their location per your environment.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is a kind old but as I found probably someone else looking for this particulary subject will find too.

So [this link](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PrivilegeSeparation) may help